# how to run multiple nokogiri screen scrape threads at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I have a website that requires using Nokogiri on many different websites to extract data. This process is ran as a background job using the delayed_job gem. However it takes around 3-4 seconds per page to run because it has to pause and wait for other websites to respond.
I am currently just running them by basically saying

```
Websites.all.each do |website|
  # screen scrape
end
```

I would like to execute them in batches rather than one each so that I dont have to wait for a server response from every site (can take up to 20 seconds on occassion).

What would be the best ruby or rails way to do this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri question at all. Your delay occurs as a result of the HTTP request waiting for the remote host to return the page. Nokogiri will parse almost instantly once the page is passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delayed job. Check out this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job).

Keep in mind most hosts charge for this type of thing.

You can also use the [spawn](https://github.com/tra/spawn) plugin if you don't care about managing threads but it is much much easier!!!

This is literally all you need to do:

1. `rails plugin/install https://github.com/tra/spawn.git`
2. Then in your controller or model add the method

For example:

```
 spawn do
    #execute your code here :)
 end
```

---

http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

https://github.com/tra/spawn

Comment: in the question i specify i am using delayed job already, (but i need it to take < 15 seconds say). i will check out spawn

Comment: Oh, sorry for missing that. No coffe yet :)

Comment: Yeah, spawn is freaking awesome but you know the story with threads in ruby.

Comment: Spawn seems to work great - much faster. I hope it is supported on Heroku

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) which enables you to make parallel http requests.

I found [a short blawg post here](http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/06/12/scraping-with-typhoeus-and-nokogiri/) about using it with Nokogiri, but I haven't tried this myself.

Wrapped in a DJ, this should do the trick with little client-side latency.

Comment: This looks interesting but I think far to complex for what I am trying to achieve. Thanks regardless

Comment: Typhoeus uses Hydra to handle the parallel tasks, but using the pair is actually quite simple. Also, [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) can do parallel tasks.

Comment: Typhoeus is pretty simple, but this doesn't really solve the problem of the fact that parsing HTML is the slow step here. I actually implemented something similar just now but Typhoeus was not really that much faster than just mapping a block to each URL. The IO obviously is much faster but the parsing essentially gets serialized.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using EventMachine to do something similar to this for a current project. There is a terrific plugin called em-http-request that allows you to make mutliple HTTP requests in parallel, as well as providing options for synchronising the responses.

From [the em-http-request github docs:](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/wiki/Parallel-Requests)

```
EventMachine.run {
  http1 = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://google.com/').get
  http2 = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://yahoo.com/').get

  http1.callback { }
  http2.callback { } 
end
```

So in your case, you could have

```
callbacks = []
Websites.all.each do |website|
    callbacks << EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(website.url).get
end

callbacks.each do |http|
    http.callback { }
end
```

Run your rails application with the thin webserver in order to get a functioning EventMachine loop:

```
bundle exec rails server thin
```

You'll also need the eventmachine and em-http-request gems. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for reminding me about 'eventmachine' gem. I always forget to reinstall